# JQuery Date Picker Formatting

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble with only one page the formatting of the date picker for Jquery. I never have had any issues before.

In Google Chrome, the first month is offset while in Internet Explorer its not. I have messed with the CSS - changing font size etc. but nothing seems to do the trick. Any help would be appreciated.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Internet Explorer:
[image: Internet Explorer]

Comment: That's because Internet Explodes is the best browser out there, and shows stuff so much better than Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure that in chrome you are not "zooming" the webpage? Sometimes when using chrome if you zoom or unzoom the page CSS and rendering have some "issues". It happened me sometimes.

Comment: @Madthew I wish that was the case but I am not zooming in or zooming out at all.

Comment: @evanvee - we really can't do any more to help you unless you provide us some source code. We've provided `css` solutions, but we can't even know specifically what classes are being applied and what global or otherwise broad css rules are floating around on your page. If you can link to your webpage or post it onto an accessible forum like jsfiddle we can almost certainly find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok then if it's not the zoom...

http://jsfiddle.net/qqMKg/1/

The two class assigned to the calendar group are

ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first

so it should work to do this way:

```
.ui-datepicker-group {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

OR

.ui-datepicker-group-first {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: cause it's a problem which only affect your first "group" you should use .ui-datepicker-group-first, the middle calendar has .ui-datepicker-group-middle.

Comment: In any case the behavior is really strange. Consider using http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ which helps eliminating this cross browser layouting differences.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your code it's hard to pinpoint the exact issue, but I'd guess that you just need to explicitly declare the `padding` on the month `select` element in your `css`. Chrome and Internet Explorer are probably just using different default `padding`, and looking at the default JQuery UI stylesheets, I don't see a `padding` value being set for `select` menus, so just add in a `css` rule that looks something like:

```
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I added these lines to the CSS and that didn't work. The code is very long and assumed this was a CSS issue.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code and/or throw everything into jsfiddle?